# join other tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT saleamount/(SELECT SUM(saleamount) 
                   from user_pr where user_id=49) *100 as totalPercentage 
from user_pr where user_id=49
```

i also want to join

```
select users.firstname from users where type=1
```

how can i combine both in one query

Answer (score -2):

Take the two table names, put JOIN between then and ON and join condition after the second one.

```
SELECT saleamount/(SELECT SUM(saleamount) 
                   from user_pr where user_id=49) *100 as totalPercentage,
       users.firstname
from user_pr JOIN users ON user_pr.user_id = users.user_id
where user_pr.user_id = 49
 and users.type = 1
```

Comment: Give table definitions and it will be easier to understand! (BTW, did my query work?)